# obtener valor de un radio html / js

Tags: javascript, html5

solicito su ayuda con lo siguiente:

En html, tengo el siguiente código de satisfacción. en js tengo una función que debe buscar la opción seleccionada, pero al ejecutar, no hace nada. Como puedo obtener la opción elegida?.

La idea es que al dar click al botón, en el label aparezca el número correspondiente al radio.

gracias por su apoyo.

soy aprendiz de estos lenguajes, por lo que me disculpo en lo extenso del código. el proyecto es para el curso que estoy haciendo. y menciono esto, debido a la restricción que tiene la herramienta entre número de caracteres vs líneas de código

```js
function validaGanaDinero()
{
    var ganaDinero = document.getElementById('ganasDinero');
    var resultadoGanadinero = "";
    var i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < ganaDinero.length; i++)
    {
        if(ganaDinero[i].checked)
        {
            resultadoGanadinero = ganaDinero(i).value;            
        }
    }
    document.resultadoDiagnositco.ganasDineroResultado.value = resultadoGanadinero;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Utopía - Perfilando</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" href="images/icon.ico">

    <!-- archivos enlazados de css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lightbox.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tema/default/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">

    <!-- google fonts en la web -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- menu navegacion -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Nosotros.html">NOSOTROS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Clientes.html">CLIENTES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Tiendita.html">TIENDITA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Descubre.html" class="active">DESCUBRE</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Diagnóstico Empresa header section -->
    <div id="diagnosticoEmpresa-header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Diagnóstico section -->
    <div id="contacto">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 col-sm-12 text-center">
                    <h2>Conozcamos Tu Empresa</h2>
                    <p>Para nosotros es importante conocer tus avances en Marketing, dilignecia el siguiente formulario para evaluar tus necesidades. Se honesto en las respuestas</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2em;">                
                <form name = "diagnostico">   
                    <div class="col-lg-4 column_1">
                        <label for="nitEmpresa">NIT</label>
                        <input name="nitEmpresa" type="text" class="form-control" id="nitEmpresa">                        

                        <label for="nameEmpresa">Nombre de la Empresa</label>
                        <input name="nameEmpresa" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameEmpresa">

                        <label for="nameContacto">Nombre Contacto</label>
                        <input name="nameContacto" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameContacto">

                        <label for="numeroCelular">Celular Contacto</label>
                        <input name="numeroCelular" type="number" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="numeroCelular">

                        <label for="emailEmpresa">E-Mail Contacto</label>
                        <input name="emailEmpresa" type="email" class="form-control" id="emailEmpresa">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 column_2">
                        <p><label for="paginaWeb">Tienes una página WEB?</label> </p>
                        <div class="inputsForm">
                            <input class="checkbox-inline" name="web" type="radio" id="web">
                            <label for="web">SI</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                            <input class="checkbox-inline" name="web" type="radio" id="web" validaWeb()>
                            <label for="web">NO</label>

                            <p><label for="nameWeb">Si tienes ¿cual es la URL?</label></p>
                            <input name="nameWeb" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameWeb">
                        </div>
                        <p><label for="tusRedesSociales">Tus Redes Sociales</label></p>
                        <div class="inputsForm">
                            <input name="tusRedesFacebook" type="checkbox" id="tusRedesFacebook" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                            <label for="tusRedesFacebook">Facebook</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="tusRedesTwitter" type="checkbox" id="tusRedesTwitter" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                            <label for="tusRedesTwitter">Twitter</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <div>
                                <input name="tusRedesLinkedin" type="checkbox" id="tusRedesLinkedin" class="checkbox-inline">
                                <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
                                <label for="tusRedesLinkedin">Linkedin</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input name="tusRedesInstagram" type="checkbox" id="tusRedesInstagram" class="checkbox-inline">
                                <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
                                <label for="tusRedesInstagram">Instagram</label>
                            </div>
                            <p><label for="tusRedesOtras">Otra, Cual?</label></p>
                            <input name="nameWeb" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameWeb">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4 column_3">
                        <p><label for="communityManager">Tienes Community Manager para Administrar tus Redes?</label></p>
                        <div class="inputsForm">
                            <input class="checkbox-inline" name="community" type="radio" id="community">
                            <label for="community">SI</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input class="checkbox-inline" name="community" type="radio" id="community">
                            <label for="community">NO</label>
                        </div>
                        <p><label for="usasPosicionador">Usas / Pagas algún posicionador para tu Sitio WEB?</label></p>
                        <div class="inputsForm">
                            <input name="usasPosicionador" type="radio" id="usasPosicionador" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="usasPosicionador">SI</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="usasPosicionador" type="radio" id="usasPosicionador" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="usasPosicionador">NO</label>
                        </div>
                        <p style="color: #337ab7; text-align: center;">De las Siguientes Opciones califica de 1 a 5, Donde 1 revela Insatisfacción y 5 Satisfacción Total</p>
                        <p><label for="ingresoMarketing">Tu Emrpesa Gana Dinero Gracias al Marketing?</label></p>
                        <div class="inputsForm">
                            <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="ganasDinero">1</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="ganasDinero">2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="ganasDinero">3</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="ganasDinero">4</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="ganasDinero">5</label>
                        </div>
                        <p><label for="estadisticas">Tienes Datos Estadísticos de las Visitas a Tu Página o lo que Buscan tus Visitantes?</label></p>
                        <div class="inputsForm">
                            <input name="tienesEstadisticas" type="radio" id="tienesEstadisticas" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="tienesEstadisticas">1</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="tienesEstadisticas" type="radio" id="tienesEstadisticas" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="tienesEstadisticas">2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="tienesEstadisticas" type="radio" id="tienesEstadisticas" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="tienesEstadisticas">3</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="tienesEstadisticas" type="radio" id="tienesEstadisticas" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="tienesEstadisticas">4</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="tienesEstadisticas" type="radio" id="tienesEstadisticas" class="checkbox-inline">
                            <label for="tienesEstadisticas">5</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <button type="button" name="btnEnviarDiagnostico" value="enviar"  onclick="enviarDiagnostico(); validaGanaDinero()" class="btn btn-default">ENVIAR</button>
                        </div>                        
                    </div>                                
                </form>
 
                <!-- Formulario Resultado Evaluación de la Emrpesa-->

                <div id="resultadoDiagnostico">
                    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2em;">
                        <form name=resultadoDiagnositco>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 column_1">
                                <label for="nitEmpresaResultado">NIT</label>
                                <input name="nitEmpresaResultado" type="text" class="form-control" id="nitEmpresaResultado">
        
                                <label for="nameEmpresaResultado">Nombre de la Empresa</label>
                                <input name="nameEmpresaResultado" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameEmpresaResultado">

                                <label for="nameContactoResultado">Nombre Contacto</label>
                                <input name="nameContactoResultado" type="text" class="form-control" id="nameContactoResultado">

                                <label for="numeroCelularResultado">Celular Contacto</label>
                                <input name="numeroCelularResultado" type="number" maxlength="10" class="form-control" id="numeroCelularResultado">

                                <label for="emailEmpresaResultado">E-Mail Contacto</label>
                                <input name="emailEmpresaResultado" type="email" class="form-control" id="emailEmpresaResultado">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 column_2">
                                <label for="ganasDineroResultado">Ganas Dinero Gracias al Marketing</label>
                                <input name="ganasDineroResultado" type="text" class="form-control" id="ganasDineroResultado" >    
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- footer-->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-4">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo">
                    <p>Interpretamos tus sueños, para traerlos a la realidad con ingenio y poco presupuesto.<br> Siéntase libre en nuestro sitio web.</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 312-232-41-45</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> info@utopia.com</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> www.utopia.com</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                    <h3>Otros Links</h3>
                    <p><a href="#">Mercadeo atípico</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Desenterrando Nichos</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Blog de la novedad</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Otros Aliados</a></p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 newsletter">
                    <h3>Boletín Mensual</h3>
                    <p>Déjanos tu correo y te lo enviamos a fin de mes.</p>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <form action="#" method="post">
                            <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="form-control" autorequired>
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn email">Enviarmelo</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!-- seccion copyright -->
    <div class="copyright">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <p>© Derechos Reservados | UTOPÍA 2020</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <ul class="social-icons">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="fa fa-envelope-o"></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- enlaces a scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No tienes ninguna etiqueta con este id `ganaDinero` te equivicaste al pasar aqui el código o asi esta en tu ejercicio?

Comment: Hola.. gracias, ya corregí,  es ganasDinero, ya no me sale el error, pero al llamar la función desde el botón, no hace nada.

Comment: Además ¿esto `document.resultadoDiagnositco` de donde sale, es decir qué es resultadoDiagnostico?

Comment: resultadoDiagnositco es un form que contiene un label ganasDineroResultado. la idea es que al dar click al botón (p. ej.) si marqué la el radio 3, en el label, me muestre 3

Comment: Agrega entonces tu HTML completo por favor, además esa etiqueta no existe entonces la sintaxis que usas no es correcta

Comment: Hola BetaM, ya copie todo el código.. mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, el HTML de los inputs es este:

```
<p style="color: #337ab7; text-align: center;">De las Siguientes Opciones califica de 1 a 5, Donde 1 revela Insatisfacción y 5 Satisfacción Total</p>
<p><label for="ingresoMarketing">Tu Emrpesa Gana Dinero Gracias al Marketing?</label></p>
<div class="inputsForm">
    <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
    <label for="ganasDinero">1</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
    <label for="ganasDinero">2</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
    <label for="ganasDinero">3</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
    <label for="ganasDinero">4</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDinero" class="checkbox-inline">
    <label for="ganasDinero">5</label>
</div>
```

El primer fallo que veo, es que usas el mismo **id** en todos los **input** y esto no es algo válido dentro de HTML así que te recomiendo que los cambias ya que un **id debe ser único**. Ligado a esto, si quieres que los **label** funcionen correctamente, en la propiedad **for** debería aparecer el id del input correspondiente:

```
<input name="ganasDinero" type="radio" id="ganasDineroUno" class="checkbox-inline">
<label for="ganasDineroUno">1</label>
```

Una vez hagas estos cambios en tu HTML, el javascript para detectar que opción está seleccionada sería:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id-boton-enviar").on('click', function () {
        var $radios = $('input[name="ganasDinero"]'); // Obtenemos los radio de 'ganas dinero
        $radios.each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                console.log('El radio seleccionado es: ' + $(this).val());
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Aquí te dejo un pequeño ejemplo funcional:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#enviar").on('click', function () {
            var $radios = $('input[name="radio-prueba"]');
            $radios.each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                    console.log('El checkbox seleccionado es: ' + $(this).val());
                }
            })
        })
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input name="radio-prueba" type="radio" class="input-custom" value="uno"> Primero <br>
  <input name="radio-prueba" type="radio" class="input-custom" value="dos"> Segundo <br>
  <input name="radio-prueba" type="radio" class="input-custom" value="tres"> Tercero <br>
  <input name="radio-prueba" type="radio" class="input-custom" value="cuatro"> Cuarto <br>
  <button type="submit" id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

**Nota:** he usado JQuery ya que he visto en tu documento que lo importas, te recomiendo usarlo.

Comment: Hola Iam, muchas gracias.. pero al ejecutarlo no pasa nada..., no muestra el dato en consola. ya incluí este script <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>, que es lo que veo distinto entre el código funcional del ejemplo y lo que yo tengo.. no se que puede ser... gracias

Comment: Hola Iam, creo el tema es el id del botón, ya lo coloqué, tal como está en la función, pero ahora me trae en consola on, cualquier opción que elija trae on.. agradezco si me das una mano.. saludos...

Comment: Hola Iam, ya encontré el problema, me faltaba el value a cada radio.. mil gracias me sirvió mucho